# Bash function defined in .bashrc not available to other scripts

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I execute this command frequently.

```
load_module virtuoso
```

It works fine in the terminal.

So I put it in a bash script named `load.sh`, which is executable.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "Hello"
    load_module virtuoso
```

but when I try to execute it using `./load.sh`, it gives this error,

```
./load.sh: line 3: load_module: command not found
```

I tried to debug it by putting `echo "hello"` in the 'load.sh' file. It prints `hello` on the screen when I execute the file, so the script works fine, I guess.
I don't think about what else to try.
Thanks

Here is the summary.

```
een212023@hertz:~/iec_lab1$ ls -la load.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 een212023 nogroup 46 Aug 19 17:59 load.sh
een212023@hertz:~/iec_lab1$ cat load.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello"
load_module virtuoso
een212023@hertz:~/iec_lab1$ load_module virtuoso
een212023@hertz:~/iec_lab1$ ./load.sh
Hello
./load.sh: line 3: load_module: command not found
een212023@hertz:~/iec_lab1$



een212023@hertz:~/iec_lab1$ type -a load_module
load_module is a function
load_module ()
{
    if already_loaded $1; then
        return 0;
    fi;
    load_vars_of_module $1;
    declare -a required_here=("${additional_required[@]}");
    declare -a conflicts_here=("${additional_conflicts[@]}");
    load_required_modules ${required_here[*]};
    unload_conflicting_modules ${conflicts_here[*]};
    load_vars_of_module $1;
    init_all_paths;
    add_paths ${additional_path[*]};
    add_ldpaths ${additional_ldpath[*]};
    add_manpaths ${additional_manpath[*]};
    add_lmpaths ${additional_lmpath[*]};
    exportvars ${additional_exports[*]};
    newaliases "${additional_aliases[@]}";
    unset ${!additional*};
    export MODULES=${MODULES}:$1
}
```

Comment: What is `load_module`? Can you add the output of `type -a load_module` to your question please? If it is e.g. an alias, it will not be available in scripts.

Comment: @ByteCommander I have added the output of "type -a load_module"

Comment: Have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/63665/103151 - if you define a shell function e.g. in your .bashrc file, this will not be available to scripts, only to your interactive shell. You might convert the function into a separate script instead, or copy it into your new script, for example.

Comment: This is why `export` exists.

Comment: @souravc. I have added `export -f load_module` in my `load.sh` file but upon executing is says, `load_module : not a function`

Comment: You need to export the function where it is defined, not where you want to load it. But if I understand the post I linked correctly, depending on where you define it, that file might not be loaded for scripts anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, you need to define your functions when loading your script.

I'm doing this by having a script file that contains my "common" functions that I use in scripts in general. Let's call this file `/path/to/bash-common.sh` - and in your case, this script would contain the function `load_module`.

Then what I'm doing is to reference this common script in all other scripts, so all my scripts begin like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /path/to/bash-common.sh
```

In your case, your `load.sh` would then be:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /path/to/bash-common.sh

echo "Hello"
load_module virtuoso
```

You can then also `source /path/to/bash-common.sh` in your `.bashrc` if you want to.

In this way, you only have to maintain all your custom functions in one place, and they are accessible anywhere you source this file (including in your interactive shell if you source it in `.bashrc`).